# running curl pulling rows sequentially in a loop

Tags: php, explode

in id.txt

Jennifer:John
Robert:William
Linda:Daniel
Elizabeth:Thomas

```
$variable = explode("\n", file_get_contents('id.txt'));
$explode = explode(":", $variable[array_rand($variable)]);


curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.questions.com/api/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
    "source": 4
}',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'CH-Languages: en-US',
    'CH-UserNAME: '.$explode[0].'',
    'CH-UserSURNAME: Token '.$explode[1].''
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I want to run each line in a loop in order
how can I do that??

1. line Jennifer:John
2. line Robert:William

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over an array sequentially, do not use `array_rand`. Use `foreach` for the purpose.

This should work

```
## be careful about line breaks. There could be more \r, \n, \r\n
## I would do explode("\n", str_replace(["\r", "\n", "\r\n"], "\n", file_get_contents('id.txt')))

## CURLOPT_USERAGENT -> set if required
## CURLOPT_POST -> generally this is preferred over CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST

$variable = explode("\n", file_get_contents('id.txt'));
foreach ($variable as $line) {
    $curl = curl_init();    ## Depending on the usage you can move this and curl_close outside the loop
    $explode = explode(":", $line);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.questions.com/api/',
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{"source": 4}',  # use json_encode to get proper json strings.
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'CH-Languages: en-US',
            'CH-UserNAME: ' . $explode[0] . '',
            'CH-UserSURNAME: Token ' . $explode[1] . ''
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    # $error = curl_error($curl);  # check to see if there are any errors
    # $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($curl);   # an array with more information about the request

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
}
```

Comment: But it runs one line and the loop stops. Didn't it run all the lines one by one?

Comment: edited the answer to include `curl_init()`

Comment: Glad it worked. Since you are a new user please read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers